# Can I "bookmark" an album in the Xbox Music Store without downloading it?

Tags: 8.0, music, xbox-music, streaming

I'd like to stream albums from the Xbox Music Store as if they were part of my music collection. I.e., they would show up in my collection like any other album. I don't have space on my phone to download all of the albums that I'd like.

Currently, if I want to stream an album, I have to open the store, search for the album, then play it from the store. Is it possible to add a bookmark to my collection, instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the album on my PC, and now it shows up on my phone (as long as I have the "show music from Xbox Music cloud" turned on).

Note that you have to start the Xbox Music app after downloading to your PC. If you download using a different program (like the Zune Desktop Software), you'll need to run Xbox Music after downloading it.